# How to get the right class context from a method when it is invoked from a callback

Tags: javascript, oop, class, callback

I'm using [Class.js](https://github.com/rauschma/class-js) for creating classes.

I'm not getting the right context inside a method when invocked from a call back function

My code is

```
WordCloud = MyClass.extend({
    init: function(data) {
        var me = this;
        (......).on("onComplete", this.draw);
    },
    show: function(word) {
        alert(word)
    },
    draw : function(words){
        console.debug(this); // prints element that triggred `onComplete` action
        console.debug(words); // "Hi"
        console.debug(me); // me is not defined
        me.show(words) // Need to call this method
    }
});
```

Problem is `draw` method is fired when an action is completed, but inside `draw` method `this` is not the actual `class` instance, but the element that triggred the callback action.

I can't pass exta arguments while calling `this.draw` as it is a call back function and `onComplete` has only one parameter.

How can I call the `show` method from `draw`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have to support Internet Explorer 8 or lower, you can use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
init: function(data) {
    var me = this;
    (......).on("onComplete", this.draw.bind(this));
}
```

Otherwise, if you're already using jQuery, you can leverage [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), which works the same way:

```
init: function(data) {
    var me = this;
    (......).on("onComplete", $.proxy(this.draw, this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a helper function for these cases.

```
function hitch(obj, func) {
    return function() {
        return obj[func].apply(obj, arguments || [])
    };
}
```

To call it you would use `hitch(this, 'draw');` instead of `this.draw`.

Or to make it even simpler you could add a simplified version to your base class

```
function hitch(func) {
    var that = this;
    return function() {
        return that[func].apply(that, arguments || [])
    };
}
```

And just call `this.hitch('draw');`.